# ag-grid's last column getting out from the table with mat-tab-group

Tags: angular, angular-material, ag-grid, mat-tab

As you can see i don't know how or why the last column from my ag-grid stays out while I use mat-tab-group,

[image]

[image]

I tried many things but nothing has worked. Any ideas are welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I tried something and it worked. On init I only load the data from the first table and I refresh the data while I click on each tab. So now the ag grid's columns are okay.

On `ngOnInit()`:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzTow.png)

And refreshing data while clicking in tabs:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sw7G2.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9ReD.png)